# Access Array of object inside a PSCustomObject Powershell

Tags: arrays, excel, powershell, pscustomobject

I have this `PSCustomObject` which I'm trying to format into a table and export it to an `.csv` file, when the `.csv` file is built, the output in the cell is `System.Object[]`.

```
$tableFindings = @() 
foreach ($item in $findings.results) { 
    $tabledata = [ordered]@{
        dnsName = $item.assets| ForEach-Object dsnName
    }
    $tableFindings += New-Object psobject -Property $tabledata
}
```

`$tableFindings` outputs

```
{
    "temporary_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "affects_rating": true,
    "assets": [
        {
            "asset": "xxxxxxxx",
            "identifier": null,
            "category": "critical",
            "dnsName": [
                "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            ],
            "is_ip": false
        },
        {
            "asset": "xxxxxxxx",
            "identifier": null,
            "category": "critical",
            "dnsName": [
                "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
                "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
            ],
            "is_ip": false
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to access the array of objects, `assets` is one of the arrays, but inside there is `dnsName` that is also an array.
Any suggestions?

Comment: You are trying to force a 3d array into a 2d array and it's going to fail. You need to either output to a format that supports nested arrays (such as JSON or XML), or flatten your array somehow (iterate nested arrays and join the results, or create an additional record for each iteration). How do you want the output to appear?

Comment: Well, JSON is morea manageable in my opinion

Comment: If you like JSON, can you just export it as that and skip the CSV? Or is somebody requiring you to convert this to CSV?

Comment: JSON has it's times where it has trouble converting it back to it's original data type such as `timespan`.

Comment: It is a requirement to export it to CSV

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you're interested in is a *flat array* of the `dnsName` values, *across all objects* stored in the `assets` array, use [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375):

```bash
$item.assets.dnsName
```

To incorporate this into `[pscustomobject]` instances that you can send to [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv):

```bash
$tableFindings = foreach ($item in $findings.results) {
  [pscustomobject] @{
    # ... add other properties as needed.
    dnsName = $item.assets.dnsName -join ' '
  }
}
```

Note the use of `-join ' '` in order to convert an array of values to a *single string*, with the elements joined with spaces, given that arrays don't stringify meaningfully with `Export-Csv`

Note how the `foreach` statement is used as an *expression*, which means that PowerShell automatically collects the `[pscustomobject]` instances output in each iteration in variable `$tableFindings`.